# Cannot get tex commands to work using tl-install-ubuntu

Tags: installing, ubuntu, paths

I tried installing texlive using the following:

https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu/blob/master/example.profile

I put the given folder and its extracted contents then ran it in this location:

```
/home/chrx/texlive/
```

executing `which tex` gives me nothing. If I try to call `tlmgr` or `pdflatex`, I get the following error:

```
bash: path: command not found
```

This is in my /etc/environment:

```
PATH="/opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:$
```

I also did the following, in an attempt to fix my links:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/* /opt/texbin
```

But still am unable to use any commands such as pdflatex.

Comment: First of you need to know where exactly did you install latex, after that you need to make that path change. If latex is actually in `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/` (check using ls on that path),  then the Ln syntax is not correct, you want a `/opt/texbin/` to be linked to the folder, not something in it, thus remove the star. Also remember, the environment file is read at login, so to see if it worked, you'll need to log out and in again.

Comment: If, as Jon suspects, you installed in your home directory then that linking us obviously wrong

Comment: Hello, yes tex is installed in /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/ . I have fixed my symlink using `sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/ /opt/texbin` but after relogging, I still do not get any commands to work. To give you a bit more info, `/usr/local/texlive/2016/` is where texlive is installed. `/home/chrx/texlive/` simply contains log files.

Comment: Alright, I added /opt/texbin in my .bashrc path, and it worked! Is this dangerous?

Comment: It will be bad if you start your editor from a menu it will never run anything bash related so will not see the path. I'd recommend adding to bashrc and dot profile (/etc/environment is probably a mistake, I tend to just use the local or global profile), again profile us read at login

Comment: Btw: you can ping others via @name

Comment: @daleif thank you for the recommendation, that worked perfectly with my editor.